# Bootstrap 3 glyphicon not working inside a button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a strange issue with Bootstrap Glyphicons. I can't get `glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal` and `glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical` to work inside a button like this:

```html
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></span>
</button>
```

If I try with for example `glyphicon glyphicon-plus` it works and other glyphs as well. What could be the issue here?

I'm using Bootstrap v3.0.3. And I can't change the Bootstrap version. I tried putting `display:inline-block` but that didn't work.

Comment: what bootstrap version do you use?

Comment: If you can't change the version of Bootstrap you use, simply put `display:inline-block` on the `glyphicon` class.

Comment: glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal and glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical not available in bootstrap V3.0.3

Comment: @MostafaBaezid Could I add them manually in some way? I need to have them.

Comment: @Doadc if you want to need this urgent basis then follow the answer which is given by Lalji Tadhani 
Bootstrap version 3.0.0 [ https://jsfiddle.net/1wr0gf9e/1/ ] he add core css version 3.0.3 and add min.css version 3.3.7  

But I dont know about if this could be make any difficulty near future

Answer (score 0):

add latest `bootstrap css` `version 3.3.7` is working now

```
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></span>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-vertical"></span>
</button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1wr0gf9e/

Bootstrap version `3.0.0`

https://jsfiddle.net/1wr0gf9e/1/

Comment: if we use min.css 3.3.7 and css 3.0.3 no effect on our project near future?

Answer (score 0):

You can use : `<span class="glyphicon">&#xe234;</span>`

Answer (score -1):

Glyphicons must be set into `<i>` tags (in "all" versions of bootstrap)

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<button class="btn btn-default">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal"></i>
</button>
```